# Any particular reason Mac OS High Sierra won’t embed Zilla Slab font?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, pdf, font

I just tried to generate a PDF using the save to PDF option in the print dialog box but for some reason or another, the font won’t embed.

The font in question is [Zilla Slab](https://github.com/mozilla/zilla-slab) and so far, this issue doesn’t seem to impact other fonts on my system.

Comment: In addition to building the fonts [you can download them](https://github.com/mozilla/zilla-slab/releases/tag/v1.002).

Comment: Which is what I did. I did precisely that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install it on your Mac first.

```
brew tap bramstein/webfonttools
brew update
brew install ttfautohint
brew install bramstein/webfonttools/sfnt2woff
brew install bramstein/webfonttools/woff2
```

Comment: Tragically, that didn't fix the issue. When opening it in Acrobat DC, it reads

`Cannot find or create the font 'LIDCYI+ZillaSlab-Bold'. Some characters may not display or print correctly.`

Comment: did you download the whole package for the fonts ? https://github.com/mozilla/zilla-slab/releases/tag/v1.002  and added it to Apple Fonts book ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: well... for some reason that font version was not included try this one https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/zilla-slab, it claims to have it